# Efficient way to get the file list and copy to local directory?

Tags: c#

I was trying to get the list of files in my remote directory and check only the file has name "test";  then copy to my local directory.

Just did a simple thing here but can someone please let me know the best way to handle this scenario.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var getfiles = new fileshare.Program();
        string[] filteredfiles =getfiles.GetFileList();

        bool b;
        foreach (string file in filteredfiles)
        { 
            if(b=file.Contains("test"))
            {
                getfiles.copytolocal(file);
            }

        }

    }

    private string[] GetFileList()
    {
        string[] filepaths = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\testserver\dev");
        return filepaths;
    }
    private void copytolocal(string filename)
    {
        File.Copy(filename, @"C:\" + filename);
    }
}
```

Even i just stuck up when i was copy the file,the filename contains the whole directory inside the filename so filename look like "\\testserver\dev\test.txt". So it failed to copy in to local.

Comment: What exactly do you expect `if(b=file.Contains("test"))` to do?

Comment: Also, do you expect any directories of the source path to be maintained?

Comment: @M.Babcock,if(b=file.Contains("test")),i have two files like XYZ.txt and test.txt in my remote,the getlist will get all the files and pass it to the condition,if its true then call my copy2local method to copy that file to my local

Comment: @M.Babcock,I just simply copy to my local directory,no direcotry path maintained in my local drive

Comment: Wouldn't that be the same as `if (file.Contains("test")`?

Comment: true,i haven't really think about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `DirectoryInfo` to filter down to any file that contains the string "test":

```
private FileInfo[] GetFileList(string pattern)
{ 
    var di = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\testserver\dev");
    return di.GetFiles(pattern);
}
```

and then:

```
 foreach (var file in GetFileList("*test*"))
 { 
     getfiles.copytolocal(file.FullName);
 }
```

Comment: Is there a reason you chose to stick with the `FileInfo[]` with `DirectoryInfo.GetFiles` over the friendlier `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` with `DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles`? Your answer isn't wrong in this regard but it seems that you may be able to save a future question by using the method and collection type that ignores files that the user doesn't have access to. --- EDIT: Upon further inspection it looks like you're trying to use the pattern from the original code provided. No explanation needed but since you changed the method so drastically I'd think you'd want to show a better way as well.

Comment: Since the file info's that are returned already match the pattern those are the ones that will be copied anyway, assuming there's not a whole lot of them it shouldn't make a difference.

Comment: That's true unless the user running the application doesn't have permission to one or many specific files or the entire directory, in which case an exception would be thrown while iterating over the collection.

Comment: +1 anyway for showing the correct way to filter a directory listing.

Comment: @BrokenGlass,tried your suggestion method still am getting "Could not find a part of the path 'C:\\\testserv\dev\test.txt'."

Comment: @Usher: That's because your `copytolocal` method is messing up your target file path, just pass both `FullName` and `Name` to the method and use the later for the target file name (`FullName` includes the full path to the file)

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for `Path.GetFileName()` (which returns a string).

Comment: ,so what i suppose to retrun back ? or how to get only the file name ?